# jQuery/Javascript foreach If/Else | If empty (do nothing) else (show foreach)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, foreach

**THIS QUESTION IS SOLVED VIA COMMENTS. WORKING SOLUTION IS POSTED BELOW**

So I got this piece of code that I am trying to adapt as it ain't showing the way I wish.

```
function writeRow(row) {
    var spans = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < num_of_fields; ++i) {
        // to do: append for select type field -> if select write: name, value, title
        // to do: add class "debug" to name, and for select tag value
        spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span> <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
    }
    spans += ' <a href="#remove-row" class="remove">&#215;</a>';
    $('#outer-list').append($('<li id="row_' + row_id++ +'">').append(spans));
}
```

The issue is with this line:

```
spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span> <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
```

The problem is that when the `row[field[i].name]` inside the `.value <span>` is empty it still shows the name and a empty value field.
So I thought to replace that line with a if/else like if `.value <span>` is empty then `//do nothing` else `CODE FROM ABOVE`.

As I am not going to ask a question without trying to fix it by myself first here are the attempts I made so far, please keep in mind that I placed all these if else at the same place as the single line of code above!

**Attempt 1**

```
if $(row[field[i].name]).length == 0) {
  // Do nothing
} else {
  spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span> <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
if $(row[field[i].name]).val().trim().length == 0) {
  // Do nothing
} else {
  spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span>  <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
}
```

The attempts are not in the right order but those 2 where left in the document as comments I tried a couple of other things as well including `:empty` but I already deleted them from the comments section.

Thanks in advance for any help. And if something is not clear please let me know.

**Attempt 3 with help from Mike C**

```
var row_id = 0; // row counter
function writeRow(row) {
    var spans = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < num_of_fields; ++i) {
        // to do: append for select type field -> if select write: name, value, title
        // to do: add class "debug" to name, and for select tag value
        if row[field[i].name].length == 0) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span> <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
        }
    }
    spans += ' <a href="#remove-row" class="remove">&#215;</a>';
    $('#outer-list').append($('<li id="row_' + row_id++ +'">').append(spans));
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a jQuery function? jQuery is going to try and retrieve elements in the DOM that match your query. Just check `row[field[i].name]` directly...

Comment: @MikeC Hey thanks for helping, I don't know what you mean with `directly`? It is inside a .js file from a Joomla Module that is why it is wrapped.

Comment: It means exactly what it looks like it means. JS doesn't require you to do anything with jQuery. Don't do `$(row[field[i].name])`. Just use `row[field[i].name]`.

Comment: Ah that is what you also meant with wrapping in jQuery. Ok I did as you suggested but it is now not showing anything. Let me update the text above to show you what I got now!

Comment: Open your console and check for errors. (F12 on Windows, Cmd + Opt + I on Mac)

Comment: Unexpected Identifier is what it is giving. Yeah I know the console. I just forgot to check that. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Update your question to include your most recent attempt so I can see where the error would be.

Comment: Hey thank you for your time helping me with this. If you want to do it in chat I am ok with that! I updated the question. @MikeC

Comment: You're missing an open parentheses. Change `if row[field[i].name].length == 0)` to `if (row[field[i].name].length == 0)`. `if` statements always require parentheses after them.

Comment: @MikeC Yes that is it. For a strange reason there is 1 span that is still showing up even while it is empty but all the others are now gone. Thank you very much. Ehm could you please post this last comment as a question so I can select it as the best answer. Thank you also for all the extra details you are giving those are really appreciated!

Comment: @MikeC, how about you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Paarth I am going to keep an eye out to this post and when MikeC adds his answer I upvote it. I am already really glad he helped me with this. In the meanwhile I added the working solution to the post and on top of the post I remind everyone of it! Hopefully this is good enough in the meanwhile.

Comment: @purple11111 it helps to have an answer (and for you to mark at as accepted) for metadata reasons as well so we can know at a glance that your question has indeed been answered completely.

Comment: @Paarth Yes I know but I can't force people to put in a answer now can I. The same as I can't force upvotes even while I do my best to create understandable and as short as possible questions/answers. When Mike C adds the answer I upvote and mark as accepted(forgot to mention that because I would do that standard). So let's hope the answer comes asap.

Comment: @purple11111 of course, I didn't mean to imply otherwise. I only mentioned it because you referenced upvoting but not approving. Enjoy your day

Comment: @Paarth You too have a great day. Thanks for showing interest into the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering it myself as I don't want to have too many questions with no answers as it could get me blocked! Can't have that. Too be clear this answers **credits should go to MikeC**. But he never posted the answer as answer but as comment. I asked him together with some others to please post a answer so we could accept it. He never did so therefore I post his answer myself.

**Working solution by Mike C**

```
var row_id = 0; // row counter
function writeRow(row) {
var spans = '';
for (var i = 0; i < num_of_fields; ++i) {
    // to do: append for select type field -> if select write: name, value, title
    // to do: add class "debug" to name, and for select tag value
    if (row[field[i].name].length == 0) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        spans += '<div><span class="name"><b>' + field[i].name + ':</b></span> <span class="value">' + row[field[i].name] + '</span></div> ';
    }
}
spans += ' <a href="#remove-row" class="remove">&#215;</a>';
$('#outer-list').append($('<li id="row_' + row_id++ +'">').append(spans));
}
```